# Using triggers to maintain a summary table in SQL

Tags: sql-server, triggers, ms-access-2010

I have a query related to using triggers in SQL Server.

I have a MAIN table in SQL Server which is linked to an MS Access front end. Multiple users update a few columns in it like Expected_date and User_Comment  throughout the day. I would like to know if I can use a trigger on the MAIN table to update a USER_SUMMARY table which basically is al ist of the users with counts of how many records have updated dates, how many do not have dates, etc:.

So my question can I invoke a stored procedure via a trigger every time a column in a record is updated? Is this better than setting up a button to run the stored procedure from MS Access to update the summary table? I thought using triggers would be more real-time and streamlined.

Kindly advise on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a VIEW is the ideal solution for that.

Triggers are a bit more difficult to maintain as it requires special cares.

- What if you LOAD a BULK data? Your trigger should handle this.
- What if data is updated? Then you need to write your trigger for INSERT **and** UPDATE, then what about DELETE?
- Should your trigger prevent insert/update/delete if something happens in your trigger? If not, how do you maintain consistency?

If it requires too much calculation and slows down your server then using a job to calculate the latest summary is the second best option IMO.

Putting a button in Access to update the summary is not a good option, as many user can push the button at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid trigger, it's going to be an overhead. I don't know which edition of sql server you are using, but if it supports jobs, I would call that stored procedure in a job. And also, use NOLOCK in your stored procedure so it doesn't affect performance.

Comment: Thanks j.v. That was exactly my thought process. Just wanted confirmation that job is the way to go. I am using SQL Server 2012. On a side note, is there no way to have a real time summary that wont require a job to be run?

Comment: I guess that you can create view that will present summary.